# Create a new Dataframe with restructured data using lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, lambda

I have a DataFrame:

[image]

and I wish to convert it to:

[image]

I think I have to use groupby and a lambda function. I just can't think of the lambda function

```
new_df = rwy16_df.groupby('height').to_frame().loc[lambda ]
```

Comment: Check Q10 in dupe

Comment: Thanks @jezrael I'm a little confused as to what is my df in the solution to Q10 in dupe as I only have one df?

Comment: One df that I wish to cumcount and pivot that is.

Comment: There are 2 columns, `rate` and `height`