# Reshaping DataFrames, turning values to colums and other values to data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, reshape

I've asked this question here:
[Create a new Dataframe with restructured data using lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61607276/create-a-new-dataframe-with-restructured-data-using-lambda-function)

Which is a duplicate here:
[How to pivot a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)

But there are few things I just can't seem to get.

I've inserted a 'count' column on my rwy16_df DataFrame using:

```
rwy16_df.insert(0, 'count', rwy16_df.groupby('cloud_range').cumcount())
```

To get:

[image]

And now I want to reshape the DataFrame to something like:

[image]

Having tried:

```
pivoted_count = pd.pivot_table(rwy16_df, values='maestro_rate', columns='cloud_range', aggfunc='count')
```

Which give me:

[image]

Comment: @jezrael added what pivot_count gives.

Comment: So `pivoted_count = pd.pivot_table(rwy16_df, values='maestro_rate', columns='cloud_range',  index='count')` ?